# Glassfish - Java EE application from 32bit to 64bit OS, incomplete DB queries?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, 32bit-64bit, glassfish-3

I'm facing very, very strange problem migrating from 32 to 64 bit system.
I have 2 envirnoments:

- Development - Windows XP 32bit
- Production - Windows 2008 server R2
  64bit

On both system I use jdk7u1 32bit, Glassfish 3.1.1 Web Profile with default JPA (eclipselink).
At production I have Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 32bit. In Glassfish I use appropriate driver from Oracle (ojdbc6.jar).
I also have Java EE app, which loads list of products from database view and shows it to user, nothing special.

When I deploy app to development computer and connect to production database everything is OK, I can see all records.
BUT when I deploy to production envirnoment named query returns only few records. There are no errors, warnings etc.
Application behaves like there would be no more records, but it's not true.
On both machines connection properties are exactly the same.
When I connect with SQL Developer from both computers I can see all records.

I have completely no idea what's going on. The only difference is OS, but this shouldn't make problems, since JDK is the same. Am I right?

Comment: Is there a pattern in missing records? E.g. the ones which are added/updated in "previous" transaction are missing? Or is it totally random?

Comment: Totaly random, records were added weeks ago, recently we migrated from oracle 10g xe database to 11g.

Comment: I noticed when I remove inner select from SQL query generating view, everything is OK.

Comment: Are there any applications on the server that may be interfering with the network traffic? Also have you check to see if the connection to oracle is timing out, I know that SQL Developer has its own set defaults. Also try connecting from SQL Plus and see what happens.

Comment: OK, problem solved. Still don't know why queries dosen't work, but we switched from sql view to sql materialized view, and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a cache problem. I remember that Toplink (base of EclipseLink) has the cache mechanism *ON* by default. So if this is the scenario:

1. If you have created/modified records from `Machine A` these modifications aren't reflected in `Machine B` since they don't have updated its cache.
2. If you created/modifed records outside of your Glassfish (EclipseLink) this records aren't updated in the EclipeLink of neither `Machine A` or `Machine B`.

You can verify it changing a record directly on database and verifying that it is reflected in both machines, if the change isn't reflected you have a cache problem and you can configure it according to following documentation:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_Cache_%28ELUG%29

Comment: Caching is turned off. When I use other db viewers like SQL developer I can see all records.

Comment: In order to discard a EclipseLink Issue, Have you tried get the data directly with JBDC using the same Datasource?